# Using Dax query to extract data from powerbi, getting an error

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a logic app that is using a power bi query to extract data. I am trying to filter the data for previous months data only. I am getting this error. Any idea what is going on? Also, if you any other idea how I can filer a large data set for previous months data (not total or sum) please let me know.

Error I am getting: "Query (4, 1) A single value for column 'Tags - Copy.DepartmentNumber' in table 'Usage details amortized' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

What I have currently:

```
DEFINE
VAR CostFilter = FILTER(VALUES('Usage details amortized'[Date]), 'Usage details amortized'[Date] >= EOMONTH ( TODAY ( ), - 1 )  + 1 )

VAR Costcolumns = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
'Usage details amortized',

'Usage details amortized'[Tags - Copy.DepartmentNumber],
'Usage details amortized'[Tags - Copy.OwnerEmail],
'Usage details amortized'[Cost],
'Usage details amortized'[Date]


TREATAS ( CostFilter,'Usage details amortized'[Date] )

)
evaluate
Costcolumns
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function cannot handle whole tables, it expects to encounter a single value. Right now, copy.departmentnumber, etc... all offer the expression multiple values.

Try to specify a value by aggregations like SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax